# adding users to sudoers - problem

Tags: centos, sudo

I have created a user, named `test`, now I want to give this user root privileges, so as root, I've added this user to the sudoers list in CentOS.

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
test    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

The problem is though, when i login as `test` I have no access to any root commands.

What could the problem be?

Thanks

Comment: What output you get?

Comment: yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `sudo` to execute root commands, e.g:

```
sudo yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's not such a good idea to do that :> It would be better to add him in an admin group.

Except for that, check root's and test's paths